# Illustrator: save a slice as PNG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, png, slices

I am slicing images from an AI file. How can I save the sliced images in PNG format? The only option I am given is JPG.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't usually use illustrator to slice the images. Photoshop is better at that, but I use Illustrator to do all my web design work.

The best way to export to the web is to separate out the elements and put artboards around them (shift+O). You can then export those artboards to the web using save for web (command+option+shift+s). With save for web you can modify the format you're exporting and the settings associated with those formats.

Just remember, to ensure your images have nice, clean lines you should select them and make sure their position (top left corner) is on an even number, not a decimal. This will ensure that you get a solid line when you save for web.

I hope that helps!

Comment: +1 I agree on not using Illustrator slice images, it is not the right tool. Everything else is right.

Comment: Great to hear! I'm glad it worked.

Comment: Why not use the slice tool which is meant for that?

Comment: Things have changed in the last 3 years.

Answer (score 0):

Once you set your output in save for web (png, jpg), that is the format which the slices will save. So once your have your slices set up, go to Save For Web, choose your format and select done. Then go to File > Save Selected Slices.

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a trick for you.

If you have many slices and you want to save all of them as PNG format do the following:

1. Select all slices
2. Copy them, (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>)
3. Make new artboard
4. Paste in place into the new artboard, (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>)
5. Now save the artboard for the web (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>)
6. From the preset, choose **PNG-24** and also make sure you check **"clip to artboard"** and at the bottom of the window, choose, **Export: All slices** then **Save**!